# Can't install Windows Server 2016 on VMware Workstation Player

Tags: windows, vmware, iso-image, windows-error-reporting

I've downloaded ISO file from Microsoft and while trying Installer disc image file option at the end it shows an error *"Windows cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms"*.

[image: ![Dialog box showing the error: "Windows cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms. Make sure the installation sources are valid and restart the installation."]

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume you are attempting to boot Windows Server from the ISO and during installation it's throwing that message. Ideally should not matter but what if you just first create a VM, check the next option 'I will install OS later' then create a VM with blank HDD preferably SCSI and then later attach the ISO as DVD? Does it still throw the error during install.

Comment: You are right, that is my problem. Once I've tried 'I will install later' option it again showed 'unsuccessful boot' at the end. But the things is I didn't change HDD settings and I am not that confident at it. I mean I don't know to configure the available options @pat2015

Comment: This is the link of my problem in VMware discussions https://communities.vmware.com/thread/598719

Comment: Also see [VMware Fix: Windows cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms](https://www.top-password.com/blog/vmware-fix-windows-cannot-find-the-microsoft-software-license-terms/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known and documented error.

During setup of the Virtual Machine you should **NOT** select the Installer Disk Image File option, but should instead select the option "**I will install the operating system later**".

Then, after the VM is fully configured, you can mount an ISO and boot to it and install Server 2016 just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things i've seen on various forums, but the only way I got it working by configuring the following VM settings:
- firmware type: BIOS
- CD/DVD(SATA): use ISO image file :

Answer (score 0):

This issue is normally caused due to Floppy drive, just set it to Auto-detect and restart the VM. This is also seen in Virtual Box, there you need to disable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).